# Spring - 405 (Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported)

Tags: javascript, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, post

I have simple code that pass form data to a spring controller via AngularJS. In chrome debugger I can see correct values are passing with the request, but I'm getting an error saying `405 (Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported)` and debug pointers in my controller doesn't hit. So I have understood that this is because of my POST request doesn't map into my controller, but I have done everything correctly.

form :-

```
<form name="empForm" ng-controller="insertEmpCtrl" ng-submit="insertEmp()">
<table>
    <tr><td>First name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" ng-model="formData.fname"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" ng-model="formData.lname"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contact no: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" ng-model="formData.contactno"/></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /> <input type="reset" value="Edit"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

AngularJS controller :-

```
empApp.controller('insertEmpCtrl',function($scope,$http){

        $scope.insertEmp = function(){


            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/IdeaOne#/addemp", $scope.formData, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            }).success(function(){console.log("done")}).error(function(){console.log("error")});

        };
    });
```

Spring controller:-

```
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model){

    return "hello";
}

//method redirects to hello.jsp
@RequestMapping(value="/addemp",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@RequestBody  Employee employee) {


    EmployeeManager.empDB.add(employee);

    return "hello";
}


//method returns a link list as a json doc to the front end
@RequestMapping(value="/viewall",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
LinkedList<Employee> viewAll(ModelMap model){


    return EmployeeManager.viewEmployees();

}
```

}

can someone help me to figure out where did I go wrong?

Comment: 1. Do you include `@Controller` inside your controller?
2. Why not use `action` in your `form`?

Comment: Please check chrome's console and see what the URL is that is being hit

Comment: value="/addemp" should be value="IdeaOne#/addemp"

Answer (score 0):

in the spring controller

`@RequestMapping(value="/addemp",method = RequestMethod.POST)`

set the path to `/addemp`. but js code post to `/IdeaOne#/addemp`. 
(I am not familiar with angularjs, I don't know the '#' sign mean in the url).

you have to make sure two paths are the same.

Comment: yes I changed it and now console gives me an error saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) "

Comment: do you still use '#' in the url. '#' means goto a named anchor, it cannot be in the path section of a url.